# How to remove " 3 commits ahead" from branch in tortoise git bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, tortoisegit

while doing git pull its showing 3 commits ahead of master/branch in tortoise git .

How to get rid of this message

I tried by stashing the changes but still getting the same error

Comment: It means you have changes that the origin doesn't have. Do you need to share those changes? Then push them. Do you need someone to review them? Push them on a separate branch and issue a PR. Do you not need those changes at all? Then reset them. Have you tried searching?

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want these additional changes, you could reset your branch to the branch you pulled:

```
git reset <branch you pulled, e.g., origin/master> --hard
```

Answer (score 0):

> while doing git pull its showing 3 commits ahead of master

This is totally normal if your pull cannot be fast forwarded because you made two local commits before pulling. There's nothing wrong so a simple solution would be to just stop worrying.

> still getting the same error

It's not an error.